# Android CI/CD with Github Actions and Fastlane

Tags: android, github, fastlane, github-actions

I am using fastlane to automate my deployments to the play store. Here is a alpha lane as an example.

```
lane :alpha do    
    gradle(task: 'clean')
    gradle(
      task: 'assemble',
      build_type: 'Release',
      properties: {
        "android.injected.signing.store.file" => ENV["ANDROID_KEYSTORE"],
        "android.injected.signing.store.password" => ENV["ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD"],
        "android.injected.signing.key.alias" => ENV["ANDROID_KEY_ALIAS"],
        "android.injected.signing.key.password" => ENV["ANDROID_KEY_PASSWORD"],
      }
    )
    upload_to_play_store(track: 'alpha')
end
```

I want to automate this deployment with Github actions. Whenever a commit to `staging` occurs, run `fastlane alpha`. The issue I am running into, however, is versioning. I need to bump the `versionCode` in my `build.gradle` file. I have been doing this manually before running `fastlane alpha`.

**I want to remove the need to bump this value manually before I commit, how can I achieve this?**

I have seen [this](https://github.com/Jems22/fastlane-plugin-increment_version_code) fastlane plugin to increment the version code. If I, for example, commit once while the versionCode is at 1, then my workflow will automatically increment the `versionCode` to 2. When I commit again, the `versionCode` will still be 1, and Github will bump it to 2. However, the play store needs `versionCode` 3. The ideal solution is to have Github query from the Google Play Store the current `versionCode` of my app and supply that `+ 1` to fastlane. I have searched for a way to do this but cannot find a solution.

Comment: I've posted my solution here which worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72084875/16470629

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried this: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/google_play_track_version_codes/ ?

```
    g = google_play_track_version_codes
    gb = google_play_track_version_codes(track: 'beta')
    ga = google_play_track_version_codes(track: 'alpha')
    max_value = [g[0].to_i, gb[0].to_i, ga[0].to_i].max
    version_updated = max_value + 1
    increment_version_code(app_project_dir: "./app", version_code: version_updated.to_i)
```

Basically I'm taking all version codes of Google Play and increasing +1 the max one, and then using the versioning plugin to update it on the build.gradle

Comment: Just to be explicit, `google_play_track_version_codes` fetches the version code from the Google Play store, correct?

Comment: Yes, and you have to check all tracks to have the biggest one.

Comment: I get this error `Google Api Error: apkNotificationMessageKeyUpgradeVersionConflict: APK specifies a version code that has already been used. - APK specifies a version code that has already been used.` even though the plugin `increment_version_code` says that `Version code has been changed to 4` (which is one more than what is in the Google play store)

Comment: Marking answer as correct and moving follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60824768/apk-version-code-conflict-despite-google-play-store-showing-otherwise)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a lane to do this as described in [this Medium post](https://medium.com/@atul.dc/increment-build-number-using-fastlane-c12b4b886ea3) by Atul Anand:

```
lane:IncrementBuildNumber do

    path = '../app/build.gradle'
    re = /versionCode\s+(\d+)/
    s = File.read(path)
    versionCode = s[re, 1].to_i
    s[re, 1] = (versionCode + 1).to_s
    f = File.new(path, 'w')
    f.write(s)
    f.close

end
```