# APK version code conflict despite Google Play Store showing otherwise

Tags: fastlane

I am using fastlane to automatically increment my version code and deploy my app. I am getting the error `apkNotificationMessageKeyUpgradeVersionConflict: APK specifies a version code that has already been used. - APK specifies a version code that has already been used` despite the highest versionCode of my releases is 3.

**Lane`bump_version_code` executing**

```
[03:47:41]: ------------------------------
[03:47:41]: Driving the lane 'android alpha' 
[03:47:42]: ------------------------------------------------------
[03:47:42]: --- Step: Switch to android bump_version_code lane ---
[03:47:42]: ------------------------------------------------------
[03:47:42]: Cruising over to lane 'android bump_version_code' 
[03:47:42]: ---------------------------------------------
[03:47:42]: --- Step: google_play_track_version_codes ---
[03:47:42]: ---------------------------------------------
[03:47:43]: Found '1' version codes in track 'production'
[03:47:43]: ---------------------------------------------
[03:47:43]: --- Step: google_play_track_version_codes ---
[03:47:43]: ---------------------------------------------
[03:47:45]: Found '1' version codes in track 'beta'
[03:47:45]: ---------------------------------------------
[03:47:45]: --- Step: google_play_track_version_codes ---
[03:47:45]: ---------------------------------------------
[03:47:46]: Found '3' version codes in track 'alpha'
[03:47:46]: ------------------------------------
[03:47:46]: --- Step: increment_version_code ---
[03:47:46]: ------------------------------------
[03:47:46]: The get_version_code plugin is looking inside your project folder (./app)!
[03:47:46]: ☝️ Version code has been changed to 4
[03:47:46]: Cruising back to lane 'android alpha'
```

**Lane context and error**

```
+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM                    | android                                                                                                           |
| PLATFORM_NAME                       | android                                                                                                           |
| LANE_NAME                           | android alpha                                                                                                     |
| VERSION_CODE                        | 4                                                                                                                 |
| GRADLE_BUILD_TYPE                   | Release                                                                                                           |
| GRADLE_ALL_APK_OUTPUT_PATHS         | ["/Users/runner/runners/2.165.2/work/myapp/myapp/client/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk"] |
| GRADLE_ALL_AAB_OUTPUT_PATHS         | []                                                                                                                |
| GRADLE_ALL_OUTPUT_JSON_OUTPUT_PATHS | ["/Users/runner/runners/2.165.2/work/myapp/myapp/client/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/output.json"]     |
| GRADLE_ALL_MAPPING_TXT_OUTPUT_PATHS | []                                                                                                                |
| GRADLE_APK_OUTPUT_PATH              | /Users/runner/runners/2.165.2/work/myapp/myapp/client/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk     |
| GRADLE_OUTPUT_JSON_OUTPUT_PATH      | /Users/runner/runners/2.165.2/work/myapp/myapp/client/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/output.json         |
+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[03:49:53]: Google Api Error: apkNotificationMessageKeyUpgradeVersionConflict: APK specifies a version code that has already been used. - APK specifies a version code that has already been used.

+------+------------------------------------------+-------------+
|                       fastlane summary                        |
+------+------------------------------------------+-------------+

| Step | Action                                   | Time (in s) |
[!] Google Api Error: apkNotificationMessageKeyUpgradeVersionConflict: APK specifies a version code that has already been used. - APK specifies a version code that has already been used.
+------+------------------------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform                         | 0           |
| 2    | Switch to android bump_version_code lane | 0           |
| 3    | google_play_track_version_codes          | 1           |
| 4    | google_play_track_version_codes          | 1           |
| 5    | google_play_track_version_codes          | 1           |
| 6    | increment_version_code                   | 0           |
| 7    | clean                                    | 47          |
| 8    | assembleRelease                          | 73          |
|    | upload_to_play_store                     | 5           |
+------+------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

**Fastfile**

```
lane :bump_version_code do
    g = google_play_track_version_codes
    gb = google_play_track_version_codes(track: 'beta')
    ga = google_play_track_version_codes(track: 'alpha')
    max_value = [g[0].to_i, gb[0].to_i, ga[0].to_i].max
    version_updated = max_value + 1
    increment_version_code(
      app_folder_name: "./app", 
      version_code: version_updated.to_i
    )
  end

  desc "Submit a new Alpha Build to Google Play"
  lane :alpha do
    bump_version_code
    gradle(task: 'clean')
    gradle(
      task: 'assemble',
      build_type: 'Release',
      properties: {
        "android.injected.signing.store.file" => ENV["ANDROID_KEYSTORE"],
        "android.injected.signing.store.password" => ENV["ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD"],
        "android.injected.signing.key.alias" => ENV["ANDROID_KEY_ALIAS"],
        "android.injected.signing.key.password" => ENV["ANDROID_KEY_PASSWORD"],
      }
    )
    upload_to_play_store(track: 'alpha')
  end
```

[image]

**Archive library**

[image]

Comment: I just saw you have some version in production that is not rolled out. Could you delete it and try it again?

Comment: @rcarba I deleted and retried but got the same error

Comment: Have you checked the Appfile ?, it might be uploading into a different package name

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Lucky_girl sorry, never figured it out sadly

Comment: In my case the problem was that I was trying to upgrade build version after the gradle step, once I put increment_version_code before gradle step I was able to upload app to Google Play,

Answer (score 15):

Go to *Google Play Console*

- "*App bundle explorer*" in the sidebar
- top right corner, click on the "*App version: *** ▾*"
- you should see all the uploaded bundle. Delete the one that have the version code you want to use.

Explanation: this happened to me while playing with Fastlane. I uploaded a bunch of .aab files and the versionCode was updated all the time (I was toying with increment_version_code plugin so this make sense). I ended up pushing a build by hand because I got an error (that has nothing to do with versionCode).
After a few days, I tried to continue working on that and wanted to upload my build "3" (versionCode: 3, as I only pushed 2 bundles in testing, the others where unused)... But during my previous days, I upload three builds 3, 4 and 5, that were causing the issue. Deleting them allowed me to push a new build with versionCode 3.

Comment: How can we get to bum the version? Is there a way to retrieve the number? Is this with the fastlane action above?

Comment: Lifesaver. Google Play Console is even more confusing than Apple Connect.

Comment: @MarcellodeSales you can fetch the previous version code with google_play_track_version_codes and then add one

Answer (score 3):

The error you got is due to after updating version code through increment_version_code, it again looks for "app/build.gradle" and picks version code from there which conflicts and then gives error.

You can solve this by 2 methods.

1. Add another lane below 'bump_version_code'.

```js
lane :gitpush do 
  git add
  git commit(path: '*', message: 'Version')
  push_to_git_remote
```

Note:- If you build your app using CI workflows, add Git authentication step in your CI.yml

```html
name: Deploy

on:
  push:
    branch: [ master ]
    
jobs:
  distribute:
    run-on: Ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
        
      - name: Build App
        run: npm run build
        
      - name: Git Config
        run: |
          git config user.name "xyz"
          git config user.email "xyz@gmail.com"
          git config user.password "xyz123"
          
      - name: Deploy
        run: fastlane alpha
```

2. Another method is to properly config google_play_track_version_code which is better way to do it.

```html
lane :increment_version_code do
  version_code = google_play_track_version_codes(
    package_name: "your package name",  #e.g. com.xyz.app
    track: "track-name",                #e.g. alpha
    json_key: "json key file path",
   )
   
   version_code_play_store = version_code[0].to_i
   update_version_code = version_code_play_store + 1
   
   increment_version_code(
    gradle_file_path: "your gradle file path",
    version_code: update_version_code.to_i
   )
end
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Point 2 creates an infinite recursive loop on increment_version_code!

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have some artifact uploaded on the artifact library that has been uploaded manually. If you delete it it will work.
You can find the Artifact Library on the left menu, inside release management.

[image]

Probably there will be some draft binaries uploaded with a code version bigger than the ones on the active ones.

Comment: Hello, I added a screenshot of my archive library to the question. As you will see, there are no APKs with the version code 4 and I do not see the ability to delete artifacts

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't saw it. Normally this is the reason what is causing this error.